# Environment.UserName gives different results for same user (casing): alternative/transformation?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

The .NET call `Environment.UserName` for the most part (>99.9% of the time) gives usernames in the same casing - for example `Awebb`.  Occasionally though I'm seeing `AWebb`.  Sometimes it seems that it relates the username as the user entered it when logging on, but other times this is confirmed as not the case.

I think this is bad design and a username should be a username, correctly-cased, no matter what: if the user decides to enter `aWEbb` then that doesn't mean the OS should start telling apps that that's their username.

That aside, what's the best/other way to obtain the current user's username - ideally without any domain - using the same security permissions required for `Environment.UserName`?  I know I could normalise everything to lowercase/uppercase but I'm really after obtaining the username correctly capitalised/formatted.

Comment: i'm really curious as to what you want a casing other than the user's preference. Usernames aren't case sensitive. Why is some other casing (other than the user entered) "more correct"?

Comment: Because in Active Directory it has a definite casing and the user will want it displayed and reported in that fashion in the app/reports.  (Same for local usernames.  Of course one is 'correct' and the others are not - KJohnstone is correct, Kjohnstone is not, kjohnstone is not, KJohnStone is not).  Also note when I say 'as they enter it' I mean when they log in to Windows: not when the username is created :)

Comment: Personally, if i were dealing with it, i would have **no** problem telling people their username will appear as the username they enter. If they want it to appear some other way on reports then either a) type it in "differently", or i will force them all lowercase.

Comment: @Ian, they are users, and the business owners or managers want to see the usernames as their IT department set them up on the PCs/in active directory.  Some 'Maureen' entering mauREEN when she logs into Windows shouldn't mean the business owners are embaressed and unable to pass their report onto their customers.  I can't see how you think it's OK to change a business requirement or rely on users to type correctly: this is a real-world situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is simply not possible.

Comment: What is not possible? To get the username as specified in AD?

Answer (score 1):

Get the name of their profile folder:

```
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, 0, 0, &s);
```

e.g. `C:\Users\KJohnstone`

Comment: As a Windows API call in C/C++, will it work in the same security environment as `Environment.UserName`?  And there's no chance a security policy might change the string processing required/involved?  (This would be deployed in locked-down corporate environments with very large IT infrastructures)

Comment: The documentation I can find, `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx`, seems to suggest the environment variable `%USERNAME%` is used, which I would guess `Environment.UserName` does too.. do you have any more info on this method?

Comment: i mean get the name of the actual *folder* on the computer - the case of the folder on the hard drive won't change with each login. SHGetKnownFolderPath returns a folder.

Comment: there is no need for the folder resembling the logon name.
how about user=PeterPan and folder=NeverLand ?